# Render a UIWeb page into an OpenGL texture offscreen

Tags: ios, opengl-es

The question has been asked several times but I believe I may have missed something. I would like to render a UIWebView into a 2D texture and draw it in 3D using OpenGL. All on iOS.

So the main idea is to use the renderInContext function being available on CALayer. However, this won't work (on iOS 5 at least), unless you add the view to a window and consequently display the ui(web)view. 
Would any body have a solution to avoid this. In practice, the UIWebview is rendered twice as a UIView and with the renderInContext.

I have tried the drawRect approach but this function is only called when UIView is displayed...

Comment: UIWebView does not draw unless it's displayed. Have you tried adding the UIWebView as a subview but in an undisplayed position and then taking its screenshot?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the answer. This what I am currently doing. However it is extremely slow... 3 frames per seconds at rendering. I am looking for a faster/cleaner solution.